Using text chunks in tensors
Got the following error:
File "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py", line 434, in 
examples = [torch.tensor(e, dtype=torch.long) for e in examples]
TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index

setproctitle.setproctitle("HyoungJoonLee")

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device('cuda:2')

if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device('cuda:2')
    print(f'CUDA device detected: {torch.cuda.get_device_name(device)}')
else:
    device = torch.device('cpu')
    print("CUDA device is not available, using CPU.")

model_name = 'microsoft/phi-2'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./output",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=2,  # Adjust based on your GPU memory
    save_steps=10_000,
    save_total_limit=2,
    logging_dir="./logs",
    logging_steps=200,
    prediction_loss_only=True,
    report_to="none",  # Use 'wandb' if logging with Weights & Biases
    learning_rate=5e-5,
    warmup_steps=500,
    resume_from_checkpoint=True,  # Allow resuming from a checkpoint
)

# Ensure the tokenizer and model are properly set up
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

# Create the dataset for training
def create_text_dataset(chunks, tokenizer, block_size=512):
    encodings = tokenizer(chunks, return_tensors="pt", max_length=block_size, truncation=True, padding="max_length")
    return torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(encodings['input_ids'])

# Prepare the dataset
def prepare_data_for_training(text_file_path, tokenizer):
    with open(text_file_path, 'r') as file:
        text = file.read().split('#'*20)

    chunks = text
    return create_text_dataset(chunks, tokenizer)

# Path to your text file containing the chunks
text_file_path = '/home/user/data/agri_llm/training_data/pretraining_chunks.txt'

# Prepare the dataset
train_dataset = prepare_data_for_training(text_file_path, tokenizer)

# Define data collator
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
)

# Start continual training
trainer.train()

# Save the final model and tokenizer
trainer.save_model("./final_model")
tokenizer.save_pretrained("./final_model")

I haven't figured out a way to fix this error. I will appreciate if someone could help with this matter.
